# Disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 in Greenlock-Express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, tls1.2, greenlock

Is there a way to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and only allow TLS 1.2 with Greenlock-Express and Node.js?

The example code for Greenlock shows something like the following:

```
var app = require("./app");

require("greenlock-express")
  .init({
     packageRoot: __dirname,
     configDir: "./greenlock.d",

     maintainerEmail: "email@example.com",

     cluster: false
})
.serve(app);
```

where `app` is the Express server object.

Can server TLS options be passed through the Greenlock initialization parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.ready()` instead of `.serve()` and you can get access to node's native `https` object customize as you wish.

```js
.ready(function (glx) {
    // Get the raw https server:
    var tlsOptions = {};
    var httpsServer = glx.httpsServer(tlsOptions, function(req, res) {
        res.end("Hello, Encrypted World!");
    });

    httpsServer.listen(443, "0.0.0.0", function() {
        console.info("Listening on ", httpsServer.address());
    });
})
```

See [examples/https/server.js](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/https/server.js).